# c3 js line chart — how to extend last step to end of range?

Tags: jquery

I want to draw a chart in which the step chart should start from the x axiz and end till the line of the x axis but the c3.js start the graph from the point first and end till the point last not draw till the line so please help me

For Example :

line start form 0 And till 2

---

---

0                 1                        2

But I want in this way

Line start from beginning of x axis and till the end of the x axiz

---

---

0                  1                     2

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you show us the code you have tried or a diagram to visualize the issue and the preferred outcome?

Comment: C3.js provide a step chart (http://c3js.org/samples/chart_step.html) in which the step chart from the 0 point of x axis and end till the end of the point 5 so i want that the step start from the starting of the x axis and till the end of the x axis not till the point "5"

Comment: So you want to extend the `x` axis even if there are no data to show?

Comment: No, I want to extend the step line not x axis